# Print dialog of Microsoft Edge opens inside child window

Tags: javascript, printing, microsoft-edge

I have some table that I need to print. In order to print that, I open up the table contents inside a child window and then print the entire page of the child window using window.print(). Sometimes, the print dialog gets stuck inside the child window only, so I have to maximize the child window in order to view the print dialog and print the contents. This issue occurs sometimes, and not always.

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE 8/9/10/11 but not in Microsoft Edge. The version of Microsoft Edge that I am using is "20.10240.16384.0". Any solution for this, so that I do not have to maximize the child window to print the contents. Also after printing the contents, the child window does not close as it does in other browsers. Any kind of assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows 10, build 10240, was the RTM version of Windows 10; I'd encourage you to check Windows Update for the 10586 update, and apply that as soon as possible. This will also update Microsoft Edge to version 25. In the meantime, can you provide a minimal reproduction of the issue?

Comment: PFB the steps:
1. Click on Print button to open a modal pop up containing the table that I need to print.
2. Left click the Print button. Child window opens up.
3. Maximize the child window to view the print dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recorded the steps using Problem Steps Recorder and found out that whenever a mouse drag and drop is fired before printing the contents of the table, the print dialog gets stuck inside the child window. For this, I disabled the mouse drag and drop events using the following script:

```
$("body").on("dragstart", function () { return false; });
$("body").on("drop", function () { return false; });
```

For the child window not closing after printing the contents, I put the window.close() on onblur event of child window:

```
<body onblur="window.close();">
```